# options or arguments passed to executables are quoted by " "

Tags: shell

There is a executbale called `app`, and it can take some options and command line args, `-l -v`, to name a few. Now I'm writing a `bash` script inside which `app` will be invoked with some options, and I did it this way,

```
opt_string="-l -v"  # this string might change according to different conditions used in if-else

# HERE is my problem
./app ${opt_string}
```

Look how I invoked `app`, typically I just invoke it in prompt shell like this:

```
./app -l -v
```

But now in this script, would it be actually this:

```
./app "-l -v"
```

cuz `${opt_string}` is a STRING quoted by `""`, if so I doubt whether `app` will run normally.

I know there might be a way around this by using `eval "./app ${opt_string}"`, but is there any way to strip the `""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BASH FAQ entry #50: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
opt_string=(-l -v)

./app "${opt_string[@]}"
```

Comment: Make `opt_string` an array? Well what if I want to append more args?

Comment: Then you append them. `opt_string+=(-n)`

Comment: I read the page, thanks for that. But there is something I don't understand, what's the difference of `./app "${opt_string[@]"}` and `./app "-l -v"`?

Comment: The former passes each array element separately. The latter passes the whole thing as one argument.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're invoking (`./app ${opt_string}`) it is fine. You define `opt_string` as a single string because you quote the value in the assignment. However, when you dereference it, you have not used quotes, so the shell will substitute its value and then split it into individual words.

when you say

```
./app "$opt_string"
```

you are passing one single argument to the app.  When you say

```
./app $opt_string
```

you are passing multiple arguments to the app.

See [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) in the bash manual.

Note that braces are *not* quotes. Curly braces (in this context) merely serve to disambiguate the variable name from the surrounding text, i.e. `echo "$opt_string_blah"` versus `echo "${opt_string}_blah"`

Comment: upvoted, I just learned that through the pages linked by @Ignacio.

Comment: One note: if one of the options can take a parameter, and that parameter is a quoted string with whitespace, you *must* use an array. Example: `opt_string='-l -v -t "this is a parameter"'; ./app $opt_string` will never work -- Due to word splitting, it is impossible to keep the parameter as a single argument. In that case, you have to use Ignacio's approach.

Comment: Yes, you're rignt, but if I don't want to use array, can I do it this way, `opt_string="-l -v -t \"this is a parameter\""; ./app $opt_string` ?

Comment: Nope, that will pass 7 arguments to ./app. You could use `eval "./app $optstring"` but that's generally considered unsafe.